# multiple `extends keyof` in overload

Tags: typescript, types, overloading

**Question:**
is it possible to have something like multiple `extends key of` in 1 overload?

**What I would like to do:**

`this.form.get("data.subdata").value`

and that would return a Typed data. Currently it returns `unknown`

**What I have done so far**

I'm creating Typed Form Control in such a way

`this.form.get("data").get("subdata").value`

and that works, but I would like not to use multiple gets, if possible.

my class is as follows:

```ts
export class TypedFormControl<T = any> extends FormControl {
  readonly valueChanges: Observable<T>;
  readonly value: T;
  setValue(value: T, options?: Object) {
    FormControl.prototype.setValue.call(this, value, options);
  }
  get<K extends keyof T>(path: K): TypedAbstractControl<T[K]>;
  get<S>(path: (string | number)[] | string): TypedAbstractControl<S>;
  get(path: (string | number)[] | string): TypedAbstractControl<any> {
    return FormControl.prototype.get.call(this, path);
  }
}
```

I was thinking to do something like this, but it definitely doesn't like it.

```
get<J extends keyof K extends keyof T>(path: K.J): TypedAbstractControl<T[K]>;
```

Update: this attempt was closer I think, but it still complains that J cannot be index of K :(

```
  get<J extends keyof K, K extends keyof T>(path: [K, J]): TypedAbstractControl<T[K][J]>;
```

I would appreciate any help, I was looking online for a while to no avail.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I got it working!

```ts
get<J extends keyof T[K], K extends keyof T>(path: [K, J]): TypedAbstractControl<T[K][J]>;
```

this allows me to  use it like this

```ts
this.form.get(['data', 'subdata']).value;
```

the value comes back with the correct type :)